# XPATH Get Attribute of Current Node

Tags: php, xpath

Having trouble getting the attribute of the current node in PHP and making a condition based on that attribute...

Example XML

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='title'>A Title</div>
    <div class='child'>some text</div>
    <div class='child'>some text</div>
    <div class='title'>A Title</div>
    <div class='child'>some text</div>
    <div class='child'>some text</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is traverse the XML in PHP and do different things based on the class of the element/node

Eg.

```
$doc->loadHTML($xml_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodeLIST = $xpath->query("//div[@class='parent']/div");
foreach ($nodeLIST as $node) {
    if (CURRENT DIV NODE ATTRIBUTE EQUALS TITLE) {
        SET $TITLE VARIABLE TO THE TEXT() OF THE CURRENT NODE
    }
    ELSEIF(CURRENT DIV NODE ATTRIBUTE EQUALS CHILD){
        SET $CHILD VARIABLE TO THE TEXT() OF THE CURRENT NODE
    }
}
```

I've tried all kind of things like the following...

```
if ($xpath->query("./[@class='title']/text()",$node)->length > 0) { }
```

But all i keep getting is PHP errors saying that my XPATH syntax is not valid. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `getAttribute()` method. Example:

```
foreach($nodeLIST as $node) {
    $attribute = $node->getAttribute('class');
    if($attribute == 'title') {
        // do something
    } elseif ($attribute == 'child') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm... Can I ask, if I fall into the elseif condition in your answer and that node has further nested DIV nodes, why doesn't $xpath->query("./div",$node) get me an array of all these nested nodes?

Comment: If you want nested divs then the XPath needs to be `.//div`.

Comment: Hiya, yes however .//div will get me all nested div nodes no matter how deep they are, whereas ./div will get me the nested div ONE level deep from the current node. I've managed to discover why $xpath->query("./div",$node) wasn't working - The markup I was reading didn't have the nested div... Grrrr - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`$node->getAttribute('class')` gives you the attribute value, `$node->textContent` the string contents of the node. I wouldn't dive into XPath to read out the string value.

Comment: Fair point, but the order in which i read the nodes is important so knowing what the text of the title node is before reading the child means I can set a title variable

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the 'title' and 'child' sets in different nodelists:

```
$titles   = $xpath->query("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='title']");
$children = $xpath->query("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']");
```

And then process them separately:

```
foreach ($titles as $title) {
   echo $title->textContent."\n";
}

foreach ($children as $child) {
   echo $child->textContent."\n";
}
```

See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/x4LA50

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I need to read the nodes in order and having TWO separate loops looks inefficient to me...